# Using scipy.stats.gaussian_kde with 2 dimensional data

Tags: scipy, multidimensional-array, kernel-density

I'm trying to use [the `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` class](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) to smooth out some discrete data collected with latitude and longitude information, so it shows up as somewhat similar to a contour map in the end, where the high densities are the peak and low densities are the valley.

I'm having a hard time putting a two-dimensional dataset into the `gaussian_kde` class. I've played around to figure out how it works with 1 dimensional data, so I thought 2 dimensional would be something along the lines of:

```
from scipy import stats
from numpy import array
data = array([[1.1, 1.1],
              [1.2, 1.2],
              [1.3, 1.3]])
kde = stats.gaussian_kde(data)
kde.evaluate([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
```

which is saying that I have 3 points at `[1.1, 1.1], [1.2, 1.2], [1.3, 1.3]`. and I want to have the kernel density estimation using from 1 to 3 using width of 1 on x and y axis.

When creating the gaussian_kde, it keeps giving me this error:

```
raise LinAlgError("singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

Looking into the source code of `gaussian_kde`, I realize that the way I'm thinking about what dataset means is completely different from how the dimensionality is calculate, but I could not find any sample code showing how multi-dimension data works with the module. Could someone help me with some sample ways to use `gaussian_kde` with multi-dimensional data?

Comment: Try it with data that's not all in a line.  I'm not sure if it should fail for that, or if it's a bug.

Answer (score 7):

[This example](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2008-July/017603.html) seems to be what you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow

# Create some dummy data
rvs = np.append(stats.norm.rvs(loc=2,scale=1,size=(2000,1)),
                stats.norm.rvs(loc=0,scale=3,size=(2000,1)),
                axis=1)

kde = stats.kde.gaussian_kde(rvs.T)

# Regular grid to evaluate kde upon
x_flat = np.r_[rvs[:,0].min():rvs[:,0].max():128j]
y_flat = np.r_[rvs[:,1].min():rvs[:,1].max():128j]
x,y = np.meshgrid(x_flat,y_flat)
grid_coords = np.append(x.reshape(-1,1),y.reshape(-1,1),axis=1)

z = kde(grid_coords.T)
z = z.reshape(128,128)

imshow(z,aspect=x_flat.ptp()/y_flat.ptp())
```

[image]

Axes need fixing, obviously.

You can also do a scatter plot of the data with

```
scatter(rvs[:,0],rvs[:,1])
```

[image]

Comment: when you say, axis need fixing, what do you mean? Because I am doing the same with a data and for some reason it gives back some excess below and above the min and max of the data

Comment: @Srivatsan: I think I just meant that it should have a more square aspect ratio

Answer (score 5):

I think you are mixing up kernel density estimation with interpolation or maybe kernel regression. KDE estimates the distribution of points if you have a larger sample of points.

I'm not sure which interpolation you want, but either the splines or rbf in scipy.interpolate will be more appropriate.

If you want one-dimensional kernel regression, then you can find a version in scikits.statsmodels with several different kernels.

update: here is an example (if this is what you want)

```
>>> data = 2 + 2*np.random.randn(2, 100)
>>> kde = stats.gaussian_kde(data)
>>> kde.evaluate(np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]))
array([ 0.02573917,  0.02470436,  0.03084282])
```

gaussian_kde has variables in rows and observations in columns, so reversed orientation from the usual in stats. In your example, all three points are on a line, so it has perfect correlation. That is, I guess, the reason for the singular matrix.

Adjusting the array orientation and adding a small noise, the example works, but still looks very concentrated, for example you don't have any sample point near (3,3):

```
>>> data = np.array([[1.1, 1.1],
              [1.2, 1.2],
              [1.3, 1.3]]).T
>>> data = data + 0.01*np.random.randn(2,3)
>>> kde = stats.gaussian_kde(data)
>>> kde.evaluate(np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]))
array([  7.70204299e+000,   1.96813149e-044,   1.45796523e-251])
```

Comment: I'm not a statistician, but my reading of KDE and kernel regression and jet's mention of "contour map" makes me think KDE is what is meant.

Answer (score 3):

I found it difficult to understand the SciPy manual's description of how `gaussian_kde` works with 2D data. Here is an explanation which is intended to complement @endolith 's example. I divided the code into several steps with comments to explain the less intuitive bits.

First, the imports:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, show
```

Create some dummy data: these are 1-D arrays of the "X" and "Y" point coordinates.

```
np.random.seed(142)  # for reproducibility
x = st.norm.rvs(loc=2, scale=1, size=2000)
y = st.norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=3, size=2000)
```

For 2-D density estimation the `gaussian_kde` object has to be initialised with an array with two rows containing the "X" and "Y" datasets. In NumPy terminology, we "stack them vertically":

```
xy = np.vstack((x, y))
```

so the "X" data is in the first row `xy[0,:]` and the "Y" data are in the second row `xy[1,:]` and `xy.shape` is `(2, 2000)`. Now create the `gaussian_kde` object:

```
dens = st.gaussian_kde(xy)
```

We will evaluate the estimated 2-D density PDF on a 2-D grid. There is more than one way of creating such a grid in NumPy. I show here an approach which is different from (but functionally equivalent to) @endolith 's method:

```
gx, gy = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():128j, y.min():y.max():128j]
gxy = np.dstack((gx, gy)) # shape is (128, 128, 2)
```

`gxy` is a 3-D array, the `[i,j]`-th element of `gxy` contains a 2-element list of the corresponding "X" and "Y" values: `gxy[i, j]` 's value is `[ gx[i], gy[j] ]`.

We have to invoke `dens()` (or `dens.pdf()` which is the same thing) on each of the 2-D grid points. NumPy has a very elegant function for this purpose:

```
z = np.apply_along_axis(dens, 2, gxy)
```

In words, the callable `dens` (could have been `dens.pdf` as well) is invoked along `axis=2` (the third axis) in the 3-D array `gxy` and the values should be returned as a 2-D array. The only glitch is that the shape of `z` will be `(128,128,1)` and not `(128,128)` what I expected. Note that the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html?highlight=apply_along_axis#numpy.apply_along_axis) says that:

> The shape of out [the return value, L.D.] is identical to the shape of arr, except along the
> axis dimension. This axis is removed, and replaced with new dimensions
> equal to the shape of the return value of func1d. So if func1d returns
> a scalar out will have one fewer dimensions than arr.

Most likely `dens()` returned a 1-long tuple and not a scalar which I was hoping for. I didn't investigate the issue any further, because this is easy to fix:

```
z = z.reshape(128, 128)
```

after which we can generate the image:

```
imshow(z, aspect=gx.ptp() / gy.ptp())
show()  # needed if you try this in PyCharm
```

Here is the image. (Note that I have implemented @endolith 's version as well and got an image indistinguishable from this one.)

[image: Output of the commands above]

Answer (score 0):

The example posted in the top answer didn't work for me. I had to tweak it little bit and it works now:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Create some dummy data
rvs = np.append(stats.norm.rvs(loc=2,scale=1,size=(2000,1)),
                stats.norm.rvs(loc=0,scale=3,size=(2000,1)),
                axis=1)

kde = stats.kde.gaussian_kde(rvs.T)

# Regular grid to evaluate kde upon
x_flat = np.r_[rvs[:,0].min():rvs[:,0].max():128j]
y_flat = np.r_[rvs[:,1].min():rvs[:,1].max():128j]
x,y = np.meshgrid(x_flat,y_flat)
grid_coords = np.append(x.reshape(-1,1),y.reshape(-1,1),axis=1)

z = kde(grid_coords.T)
z = z.reshape(128,128)

plt.imshow(z,aspect=x_flat.ptp()/y_flat.ptp())
plt.show()
```