# How to plot the best line or outer line of an elliptic scatter figure in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, curve-fitting

I read some parameters from a text file using the following code:

```
H, OD, c, b, orc = np.genfromtxt('textfile.txt', unpack = True)
```

I plot them two by two using the simple code

```
plt.plot(H[i], c[i], 'bo')
```

Finally we have 10 plots for these 5 parameters. The plots are something like solid circle or solid elliptic or a closed solid figure using 300,000 points. similar to

[image: this scatter plot]

How could I plot the boundary line or fit line, I mean the outer line surrounded the figure. similar to

[image: this plot]
<sub>(source: [springernature.com](https://media.springernature.com/lw785/springer-static/image/art%3A10.1007%2Fs11214-018-0466-9/MediaObjects/11214_2018_466_Fig12_HTML.gif))</sub>

Comment: does [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/bound-chart-area.htm) help any? *The lowest x value point is chosen as the Starting point and the each other point is checked to find the one that causes the smallest change in angle.* This is O(n^2) by the way..

Comment: If you can use Seaborn, you can use kdeplot: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html

Otherwise, you will need to fit a Gaussian to your data by yourself and display a contour plot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128699/using-scipy-stats-gaussian-kde-with-2-dimensional-data

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I am searching to find a way, library, module, etc to do that in Python.

Comment: @Ehsan It is the algorithm I meant, not its excel implementation but, yeah, there should be something ready to use. Take a look at Kef's suggestion. Seems promising!

Comment: Do you want a convex hull  or a type of contour plot?

Comment: @mikuszefski It can be convex hull but I need some exact model. and I dont know what is exist out there for this issue.

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768197/bounding-ellipse); might help.